# base64decode a string like "b'Mw=='" (containing literal b' substring)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encoded a comma delimited list (ex. `"1,2,3"`) of ids to base64 then the returned data from the form looks like `x` below.

I tried decoding and encoding and all sorts of things but nothing seems to return a the original string.

```
x = "b'Mw=='"

base64.b64decode(x)
# b'l\xcc'

x.decode()
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

y = x.encode('utf-8')
print(y)
# b"b'Mw=='"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `base64.b64decode(b'Mw==')`. That thing is supposed to be [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), not a string.

Comment: Remove double quotes, i.e. `x = b'Mw=='`. Also, `b64decode` does not modify the original string (strings are immutable). It returns a new one.

Comment: I don't control the doublequotes or this is an `xy` problem. The form I receive the data from has put quotes around the bytes already.

Comment: Someone called `str()` on a bytes object instead of `decode()`, giving you a broken `x`. Need to fix that upstream.

Comment: @AndrasDeak you are right it is ultimately an upstream error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `b'...'` in your data, that's the `repr()`esentation of a bytestring.

If you can't get your data source to fix their content (it *should* just be `Mw==`: what they're giving you isn't valid base64 encoding!), you can use `ast.literal_eval()` to read it into a bytestring:

```
>>> import ast, base64
>>> x = "b'Mw=='"
>>> base64.b64decode(ast.literal_eval(x))
'3'
```

Comment: Technically this solves the problem but my real issue was upstream feeding me the incorrectly encoded `x`. So I accept this answer for those who can not control the upstream but in my case I was able to fix the upstream source and decode my string as originally expected.